# Why does PHP allow passing a literal to a pass-by-reference parameter in one case but not others?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, php-internals

The function `array_shift()` takes one parameter by reference. Passing an array literal causes a fatal error:

> $ php -r 'var_export(array_shift(array("Test #0"));';echo
>
> Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in Command line code on line 1

This fails as expected. However, PHP behaves strangely when the function is called with call_user_func_array:

```
<?php
var_export(call_user_func_array("array_shift", array(array("Test #1"))));
echo "\n";

$arg1 = array("Test #2");
var_export(call_user_func_array("array_shift", array($arg1)));
echo "\n";

$args = array(array("Test #3"));
var_export(call_user_func_array("array_shift", $args));
echo "\n";
```

When executed:

> $ php test.php
>
> 'Test #1'
>
> Warning: Parameter 1 to array_shift() expected to be a reference, value given in /Users/kcc/test.php on line 6
>   NULL
>
> Warning: Parameter 1 to array_shift() expected to be a reference, value given in /Users/kcc/test.php on line 10
>   NULL

It's understandable that `call_user_func_array()` wouldn't trigger a fatal error, but why does the first form work fine?

Comment: Is tere supposed to be a third closing parenthesis here? `$ php -r 'var_export(array_shift(array("Test #0"));';echo`

Comment: I don't know enough about the internals to explain why (though the existence of a variable seems to force PHP to return the value of the expression, rather than a reference to it)... but this has been "fixed" in PHP7. You'll get a warning on all three.

Comment: Just a guess, but since you are using call_user_func_array, when calling array_shift the second argument is a variable available within the function. So you are shifting off that variable, not a literal array value. A function defined `function test($a, $b){ $a($b); }`, if calling `array_shift` in that function, `$b` is a local variable, not a language construct like `array()`. So you would be passing a reference to the local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [call_user_func_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) documentation:

> Before PHP 5.4, referenced variables in `param_arr` are passed to the function by reference, regardless of whether the function expects the respective parameter to be passed by reference. This form of call-time pass by reference does not emit a deprecation notice, but it is nonetheless deprecated, and has been removed in PHP 5.4. Furthermore, this does not apply to internal functions, for which the function signature is honored. Passing by value when the function expects a parameter by reference results in a warning and having `call_user_func()` return `FALSE` (**there is, however, an exception for passed values with reference count = 1, such as in literals**, as these can be turned into references without ill effects — but also without writes to that value having any effect —; do not rely in this behavior, though, as the reference count is an implementation detail and the soundness of this behavior is questionable).

(emphasis mine)

Since PHP 5.4, `call_user_func_array()` passes all of its arguments by value to the specified `$callback`, except in the case of the exception bolded in the manual quote above.

In `Test #1`, you have a pure literal, so you hit the special exception described in the documentation: the literal can be turned into a reference with no unwanted side-effects (because it will just be thrown away when `call_user_func_array()` is done).

In `Test #2` and `Test #3`, you don't have a pure literal, and because internally, `array_shift` is defined as taking its parameter by reference, `call_user_func_array()` raises the warning described above.

In PHP 7, `Test #1` is "fixed", and now correctly emits the warning.